# Merging overlapping features into one file with attributes (PostGIS)

Tags: postgis, topography, os-mastermap

I am working with os topography files which are split into points, lines and polygons. At the moment, I am trying to merge the separate files into a single topography file.

Using this source ([Using PostGIS to find the overall difference between two (large) polygon datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390281/using-postgis-to-find-the-overall-difference-between-two-large-polygon-dataset/390310#390310)) I have managed to merge my polygon (test_area_2) and polyline (test_line_2) shapefiles together successfully - below.

```
DROP TABLE temp;
CREATE TABLE temp as  (
        
    SELECT ST_Multi(COALESCE(
         ST_Difference(a.geom, c.geom),
         a.geom
       )) AS geom
FROM   test_area_2 AS a

CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ST_Union(b.geom) as geom
  FROM   test_line_2 AS b
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) 
)   
    AS c);
```

However, it does not export all the associated attribute columns (i.e. test_area_2.*). I have tried different combinations to do this but so far unsuccessful.

How can I do this?